# Query the two cities hackerRank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there was already question and answer about it. I am using SQL Server.

I have these queries:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 city, LEN(city) 
FROM station 
WHERE LEN(city) = (SELECT MIN(LEN(city)) FROM station) 
  AND ((lat_n > 0) AND (long_w >  0))  
ORDER BY city ASC;

SELECT TOP 1 city, LEN(city) 
FROM station 
WHERE LEN(city) = (SELECT MAX(LEN(city)) FROM station) 
  AND ((lat_n > 0) AND (long_w >  0)) 
ORDER BY city ASC;
```

They do work fine and give me the right answer. But when I run them together I always get 'wrong answer' .

The only difference from what they want is the following

**Correct:**

```
Amo 3  
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

**Wrong:** - the one I've got

```
Amo 3  
city  
---- -  
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

If I run each query I get a one liner answer.

But if I run both as 2 lines I do have these  2 extra line which I believe are the issue.

Now I do not know how to get rid of them.

I do not know if it is browser issue or the syntax has to be different since running in their sandbox.

Comment: It's hard to guess what those queries are supposed to do without any data or expected results. Matching rows based on string lengths is almost certainly wrong. The queries are certainly unusual and perform badly.

Comment: I believe your question is not immediately related to an SQL problem but possibly how to process the returned results in your website's script (PHP?). The second line in the "wrong result" looks like it's the column name of the query result.

Comment: `I do have these 2 extra line` SQL doesn't return extra lines. Based on that alone, the question should be closed as unreproducible. This is 100% a client-side problem in how the results are displayed. I removed the unrelated `sql-server` tag and added `html` as a generic guess. A desktop application wouldn't allow mixing up UI elements like this. Add the proper tag and your actual client code

Comment: hits is from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5/problem?isFullScreen=true.   in a I am using MS SQL SERVER from the options. I do not have access to the db itself since it is onto their portaland you run the code in a sand box. the queries by themselves works. If I run any of them on their own they do get their right answer. It is just when I run them as 2 lines I got the 2 extra line City and ---- - .

Comment: here a screenshot https://ctrlv.link/Q2H8.

Comment: Well, from your screeshot it's saying: "Please enter the query in a single line". This probably excludes multiple queries to solve the problem.

Comment: at the bottom....  Note 
You can write two separate queries to get the desired output. It need not be a single query.

Comment: Maybe UNION the two queries qogether SELECT [min]... UNION SELECT [max]... ;

Comment: Where is the connection to 'html' ? I removed this tag and added 'sql' and 'sql-server' to your question.

Comment: html?  may be because I thought the result via the browser did not display properly.

Answer (score 0):

ok
I have finally found a solution... MSSQL
It took me long enough

```
    SELECT 
       top 2 city, len(city)
    FROM 
        station 
    WHERE (
        len(city) = (SELECT MIN(len(city)) FROM station ) 
      OR 
        len(city) = (SELECT MAX(len(city)) FROM station)) 
      AND 
         ((lat_n > 0) 
      AND 
         (long_w >  0)
   ) ORDER BY len(city) DESC, city;
```